# Virtual Sitecore User Group - Budapest #13

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

### Topics

***1. TRUE OMNICHANNEL CONTENT DELIVERY WITH SITECORE EXPERIENCE EDGE FOR CONTENT HUB***

> With the release of Sitecore Experience Edge for Content Hub you have the freedom to create experiences for any channel consuming content Sitecore’s scalable Content Delivery service. During this session Pieter will address why Sitecore Experience Edge has been build and what problems it solves for our customers. Explaining the difference between omni-channel content management and web content management. Wrapping-up with an example omni-channel consumer story that highlights the perfect use case for omni-channel content.
> Followed directly with a live demo from Mark. During this demo, Mark will show how you can query the API endpoints, create new content types in Content Hub, publish the content to the Sitecore Experience Edge and consume that content using Next.js.

by **Pieter Brinkman** (Senior Director Technical Marketing at Sitecore) & **Mark van Aalst** (Senior Technical Evangelist at Sitecore)

‍♂️ ***2. FROM HERO TO ZERO AND BACK TO HERO***

> Story of Sitecore Backend Developer becoming React Frontend Developer using Sitecore JSS.

by **Peter Procházka**, Solutions Architect at Accenture, Sitecore MVP.

The presentations will be held in English. Ask your questions or add your comments to the presentations while it's running. Streaming platform will be chosen soon and you will be informed! RSVP to the event to be up to date!

**When (UTC):** Thursday, April 15, 2020 6:00 PM

**Where:** RSVP to the meetup to join online!

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/276514226/)**

Comment: I see that none of my lazy co-moderators picked this up, sorry for the delay ;-)   The promotion is live now

Comment: @MarkCassidy haha, thanks! :)